# Difference between <? extends CustomClass> and <CustomClass> Genericity

Tags: java, list, class, generics, design-patterns

What is the difference between theses List.

```
ArrayList<? extends CustomClass> test = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
ArrayList<CustomClass> test2= new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
```

or between theses two class.

```
class test <T extends CustomClass> {

 public void <T> someThings(T arg){}

}

class test {

 public void someThings(CustomClass arg){}

}
```

`T` is extending `CustomClass` so using a subclass of `CustomClass` for argument in the `someThings()` method should work.

But it does exactly the same than in the second situtation, we can also pass a subclass of `CustomClass` as an argument.

What is the exactly difference betweem theses two solution ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have subclasses:

```java
public class SuperClass {
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
}
```

Then:

```java
List<? extends SuperClass> test1 = new ArrayList<SubClass>(); // ok
List<SuperClass> test2 = new ArrayList<SubClass>(); // ko, won't compile
```

Giving the message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<SubClass> to ArrayList<SuperClass>`.

---

When parameterizing methods, there no *real* difference between:

```java
public <T extends SuperClass> void method(T arg)
```

And:

```java
public void method(SuperClass arg)
```

It is interesting to parameterize a method when returning the said type:

```java
public <T extends SuperClass> T method(T arg)
```

Comment: Ok, but in the case that we instantiate the List this way 

List<SuperClass> test2 = new ArrayList<SuperClass>();

what is the difference with

List<? extends SuperClass> test1 = new ArrayList<SuperClass>();